# Is iterating over a dictionary constant time? (Since lookup is constant?)

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, big-o

My question is around the constant O(1) lookup time for a dictionary.

So I have a dictionary of key/value pairs. And I have a list of items I am iterating through. For each item, I want to check whether it is in the dictionary, and if it is not in there, I want to add it, otherwise I will simply pass. Is this constant or linear time?

Because I am iterating over the whole dictionary, however I know that lookup in a dictionary is O(1)?- this has confused me so much!

My real question is, is the overall time complexity O(N^2)? Because for each item in the list, I am checking the entire dictionary to see if it is there, and I am adding each item to it if it is not there.

Comment: If you're iterating over a list, that's already linear time. Check [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for Python specifically.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes it is linear time for iterating over the list. However, for each item in the list, I will be checking the entire dictionary; so does this make the overall complexity O(n^2) - this was my real question

Comment: Avarage case, you get O(n), because dictionary lookup is constant O(1), however considering amortized worst case it is O(n^2) (which almost certainly won't happen in real situations..).

Comment: Interestingly, iterating over a list and checking if it's in the dictionary is *nothing* like iterating over the dictionary and checking if it's in the list :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overall complexity is *O*(*n*). You are performing *n* lookups each of which takes *O*(1) time, for a combined time complexity of *O*(*n*×1) = *O*(*n*).

> For each item, I want to check whether it is in the dictionary, and if it is not in there, I want to add it...

Side note, checking and adding in separate steps is a common code smell. It's usually better to simply attempt an insertion. The insertion will fail if the key already exists, no need to check first. This is more efficient as it does one lookup instead of two&mdash—after all, insertion has to do the exact same lookup as a key check to figure out *where* to insert. Checking first merely duplicates work.

In the worst case, it's not just an efficiency improvement but also one of correctness. If the dictionary is accessed by multiple threads a check-then-insert access pattern can result in a [time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTOU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) error. Namely, you might check if the key exists; it doesn't, so you attempt to insert it; but meanwhile another thread has snuck in and inserted the same key while you weren't looking, and you overwrite the other thread's entry.

Another common TOCTOU error is checking if a file exists and creating it if it doesn't. See [Common Weakness Enumeration 367 - TOCTOU Race Condition](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html) for more details and examples.

Comment: But I am performing n lookups for n items no? This is the part I don't understand

Comment: Or rather I am performing n-1 lookups for n items. In the worst case, none of the items in the list are in the dictionary.

Comment: Ohh, so the lookup (what I called iterating over the dictionary) is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

When we say that the lookup in a dictionnary is O(1), it means that when looking up in a dictionnary you execute much less operations than the size of the dictionnary (without entering in the details of what is considered an operation).

If you do n lookups, you execute a number of operations around the size of the dictionnary. So you say it's O(n), where n is the size of the dictionnary.

The O notation in this case is just a relative measure to see how much operations you execute compared to the size of the input.

In other words, O notation is the language we use for talking about how long an algorithm takes to run. It is how we compare the efficiency of different approaches to a problem. With O notation we express the runtime in terms of how quickly it grows relative to the input, as the input gets larger .

For the formal definition, check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score -2):

Now I am not sure what you are asking but, to implement that the code is:

```
foo_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foo_dict = {1: "1", 4: "4", 6: "6"}

for i in foo_list:
    if i not in foo_dict:
        foo_dict[i] = str(i)
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote since I'm lenient on new contributors, but this doesn't really answer the question. Just out of courtesy, what I tend to do if the question is ambiguous is to offer multiple sections in my answer each showing the assumptions for that section. If I'm not sure what the question is at all (as opposed to thinking it could be one of several), I'll probably just not answer :-)